# running yew framework sample code - error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, yew

I am trying to run the [yew framework](https://github.com/yewstack/yew) [sample code](https://github.com/yewstack/yew/tree/master/examples) and I running into this error when running `cargo install trunk wasm-bindgen-cli`

``` error: linking with ``cc`` failed: exit status: 1 ```

I am running `rustc 1.60.0-nightly (2681f253b 2022-02-01)`

Here's the output:

```
error: failed to compile `trunk v0.14.0`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `/var/folders/gp/n2f6jp996t93rzc9dhyldyr40000gn/T/cargo-installicBllO`
```

Caused by:
build failed
error: failed to compile `wasm-bindgen-cli v0.2.79`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `/var/folders/gp/n2f6jp996t93rzc9dhyldyr40000gn/T/cargo-installCKNe4D`

Caused by:
build failed
Summary Failed to install trunk, wasm-bindgen-cli (see error(s) above).
error: some crates failed to install

output:

```
//some output before
JmxvNA/release/build/proc-macro2-a0e6a8ec316499c4/build_script_build-a0e6a8ec316499c4" "-Wl,-dead_strip" "-nodefaultlibs" "-fuse-ld=/usr/local/bin/zld"
  = note: clang: error: invalid linker name in argument '-fuse-ld=/usr/local/bin/zld'
          

error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
  |
  = note: "cc" "-m64" "-arch" "x86_64" "/var/folder

//Some output here
note: clang: error: invalid linker name in argument '-fuse-ld=/usr/local/bin/zld'
          

error: failed to compile `trunk v0.14.0`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `/var/folders/gp/n2f6jp996t93rzc9dhyldyr40000gn/T/cargo-installkiOHan`

Caused by:
  build failed
error: failed to compile `wasm-bindgen-cli v0.2.79`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `/var/folders/gp/n2f6jp996t93rzc9dhyldyr40000gn/T/cargo-installJmxvNA`

Caused by:
  build failed
     Summary Failed to install trunk, wasm-bindgen-cli (see error(s) above).
error: some crates failed to install
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide the full command output.

Comment: The complete output is too long to put in the post but I'll try to post the most relevant parts.

Comment: Does `/usr/local/bin/zld` exist?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/install-trunk-error-36c9st?file=/error.log 
I met the same error when run `cargo install trunk`.
Please Check this full log